# How to properly setup a npm package using VUE 2 Composition API?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-composition-api

I have a npm package using components which are calling `inject`:

```js
<template>
  <div>{{ hub.message }}</div>
</template>
<script>
import { inject } from "@vue/composition-api";
export default {
  name: "test",
  setup() {
    const hub = inject("HUB");

    return { hub };
  },
};
</script>
```

In lib package.json I have set `@vue/composition-api` as a dev and peer dependency.

In my main project (not library), I'm registering Composition API and using provide like this:

```js
import Vue from "vue";
import VueCompositionApi from "@vue/composition-api";
Vue.use(VueCompositionApi);
import App from "./App.vue";

import { hub } from "../lib/hub";
import { provide } from "@vue/composition-api";

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  setup() {
    provide("HUB", hub);
  },
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount("#app");
```

Hub is a simple object:

```js
export const hub = {
  message: null,

  init: function() {
    this.message = "I'm here";
  },
};
```

But I'm getting 
`Error in data(): "Error: [vue-composition-api] "inject" get called outside of "setup()""`

I have also prepared a small demo demonstrating the issue:
https://github.com/JiProchazka/composition-api-test

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: i this component https://github.com/boussadjra/vue-spring-calendar i organised the DI and it works fine, check the following files : `useContext.js` , `SpringCalendar.vue` and `Days.vue`

Comment: Is this meant to be a library? You are calling Vue.use(CompositionApi) in the library as well? It seems to be a proper app, not a library.

Comment: Not inside the component, but you have to add `Vue.use(CompositionApi)` to the main.js of your project in order to use my component

Comment: I of course call `Vue.use(CompositionApi)` in main.js of my main project.

Comment: Hello again, did you find a solution?